# How to pass Custom Object from one Activity to Another Activity in Android?

Tags: java, android, gson

I want to send a custom Object from on Activity to Another. And Somehow i can't use Serializable or Parcelable. This is what i am doing.

from A -> B

```
Result<String> res = (Result<String>) o;
intent.putExtra("response", new Gson().toJson(res));
```

And in B i am doing this -

```
jsonMyObject = intent.getStringExtra("response");
                Result<String> temp_result = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMyObject, new TypeToken<Result<String>>() {
                }.getType());
```

But it is giving me error: **Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 22 path $.data**

Comment: Typecasting object O into desirable object.

Answer (score 0):

Found the Answer myself.

I should be doing this instead in Activity B

```
jsonMyObject = intent.getStringExtra("response");
                Result<String> temp_result = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMyObject, Result.class);
```

Comment: This will work, provided the string isn't too large.  The other solution is to make Result implement either Parcelable or Serializable.